# why is the the function not getting called and throwing me an error?

Tags: javascript, scope

The below is my code

```
function callName() {
    var name="x";

    function printName(){
        alert(name);
    }

    return printName;
}

name = callName();
alert(name);
name();
```

When i execute it, the alert statement is printing the printName function perfectly, but the function call name() is giving an error stating string is not a function. if scope is the problem the alert should have printed the name instead of the function. I am trying to understand closures here and was trying this out and got confused with the scope management in js.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't declared `name` in the outer scope, so it's using the global scope, and is actually pointing to `window.name`.  Just declare it as a local variable, and you're set:

```
function callName() {
    var name="x";

    function printName(){
        alert(name);
    }

    return printName;
}

var name = callName();
alert(name);
name();
```

Since `window.name` is the name of the window, when you assign to it, it's assigning the string contents to the name of the window, and is still a string - that's why you can't call it with `name()`.

Note that this will only work if this code itself is within another scope - if it's on the global scope, even using `var name` won't help, as it will still conflict with the global `window.name` property.

Comment: Better explanation than mine.

Comment: lol Too funny. I told them the issue, and everyone down votes me because they're fixed on printName. Agreed though, this guy explained it much better than I did.

Comment: lol Except that I posted the same thing you did, minus going into detail on how they should code all of it.

Comment: are you saying that even if i assign an object instance to name, it would still be converted to a string and then assigned..?

Comment: @BlackPanther [Yes](http://jsfiddle.net/vx4d3voe/), assuming you're still talking about `window.name`.  If it's a normal variable, it's fine.

Comment: @JamesThorpe i have a doubt. even if i declare name as `var name` outsite the function, it is not working in chrome and firefox. But works fine in IE

Comment: @BlackPanther There must be something else going on in your environment - the above works fine for me in Chrome

Comment: @JamesThorpe can you check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uw1tcw9g/) fiddle in chrome?

Comment: sorry, yes you're right - it was the way I was testing it in jsfiddle that wasn't showing the problem.  So you can't redeclare it in the global context then - it's still conflicting with `window.name`, which makes sense.

Comment: @BlackPanther I've added another sentence to the answer to clarify

Comment: @JamesThorpe thx for the response :) the code works fine in javascript section in fiddle as you said..  but somehow, IE 9 doesn't pose this restriction. I wonder if there are other such pitfalls in javascript.

Comment: @BlackPanther It works fine because by default jsfiddle wraps it in `onload` (ie another scope).  [Here's a version](https://jsfiddle.net/uw1tcw9g/1/) where it's in the JS section but placed straight into `<head>` - there's a setting in the top left that controls this - this one doesn't work as it's now in the global scope.

Comment: And [here's a version](https://jsfiddle.net/uw1tcw9g/2/) where it's still in `<head>`, but it's not locally scoped in the `test` function, and it works fine

Comment: And for completeness, [here's a version](https://jsfiddle.net/uw1tcw9g/3/) that doesn't have `var` within this local scope, so it's going back to the global scope, and no longer works

Comment: yes i saw that.. but in Internet Explorer 9 it is not conflicting with `window.name`. If you open [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uw1tcw9g/) in IE, it wont throw any error

Comment: Yeah it's odd - I may try to investigate or dig into specs to see if I can find out why IE behaves like this a bit later when I have time.  I'm on IE11 and it still seems to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

That is because inside `callName()` you set the var `name` to string. If you do this:

```
var name = callName();
```

You will be creating a new var `name` different of the one inside `callName()`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h79urjbh/)

Comment: Haha... I bumped you back up to 0. I posted the right answer also and got spammed with it too.

Comment: I posted first, but James posted a better explanation.

Comment: VoteUp, explanation the problem, easy go get, fine solution :)

Comment: Agreed. I was sitting here watching all of it go down. Not sure why they down voted you though, even if James explained it better. You were still correct in what you said.

Comment: Actually, whether you do `var ` or not, the variable `name` outside of `callName` is a different `name` to the one inside the function.

Comment: adding var name outside the scope, does work, but the part on having a var inside the function doesnt matter here.. but thx for ur answer.. :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe even if both have no `var` declaration?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown No - I meant with or without the `var` on the outer variable, ie as per the OP, and mine/your answer.  Without var on the inner `name`, that too will refer to `window.name`.

Comment: @JamesThorpe sure, thats what i thought

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I was just trying to clarify your answer a little - "if you do this... you will be creating a new var `name` different..." - actually it's already different, even without the `var...`, because the inner `name` has been independently declared

Comment: @JamesThorpe yeah I got it, I just wanted to check I understand right. Thank you for your explanation.